# Prestashop and smarty php code

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop

I want to include in prestashop (smarty) in the folder "/themes/my_template/modules/my_modul" a php file in the tpl.

example:

```
    <?php
include('/tools/smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty;

$vorname="Horst";
$nachname="Meyer";

$smarty->assign('vorname',$vorname);
$smarty->assign('nachname',$nachname);

// ausgabe
$smarty->display('my_template.tpl');
?>
```

but the variable {$vorname} is not displayed. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, that your way will work.

You are working inside templates directory, so you have to create a *.tpl files there.

If you want to include php file, you can use include_php directive inside your template http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.php.tpl

If you want to display an variable inside template, you can use http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl